# How to run remote external commands on meteor server from MeteorJS Application?

Tags: node.js, meteor, casperjs

I create some CasperJS scripts that login into Duolingo, do click on a module and open as If I were playing there.

I create a simple meteorJS application and I want that when I click a button be able to execute that casperjs script. I am looking for someone with that experience to help me or oriented me in the right way because I don't have much idea of what can I use to achieve this little personal game.

I have read about RPC - Remote Procedure Call of MeteorJS, and I have read that with PHP and NodeJS you can run a function that executes the script as if I were typing the commands to run the script.
I have found these resources: 
ShellJS: https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs 
and NodeJS child process: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback.

but I don't have much experience, I am doing this to learn more about CasperJS, MeteorJS.

What I need is to be able to run this command -> "casperjs duolingo.js --engine=slimerjs --disk-cache=no" using my Meteorjs app so I can continue creating my little automation bot to play Duolingo totality.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The second link in your question should be directly applicable. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a "simple" if you know what to do :-)

#### Just to know what will happen:

1.) You create a method on server side which can run external processes
2.) You create a meteor remote method which can be called by client
3.) You create the action on client and call remote meteor method
4.) You bind the click event to call the action on client

#### Method to call external processes

```
process_exec_sync = function (command) {
  // Load future from fibers
  var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");
  // Load exec
  var child = Npm.require("child_process");
  // Create new future
  var future = new Future();
  // Run command synchronous
  child.exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // return an onbject to identify error and success
    var result = {};
    // test for error
    if (error) {
      result.error = error;
    }
    // return stdout
    result.stdout = stdout;
    future.return(result);
  });
  // wait for future
  return future.wait();
}
```

#### Meteor remote server method

```
// define server methods so that the clients will have access to server components
Meteor.methods({
  runCasperJS: function() {
    // This method call won't return immediately, it will wait for the
    // asynchronous code to finish, so we call unblock to allow this client
    // to queue other method calls (see Meteor docs)
    this.unblock();
    // run synchonous system command
    var result = process_exec_sync('casperjs duolingo.js --engine=slimerjs --disk-cache=no');
    // check for error
    if (result.error) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("exec-fail", "Error running CasperJS: " + result.error.message);
    }
    // success
    return true;
  }
})
```

#### Client event and remote method call

```
Template.mytemplate.events({
  'click #run-casper': function(e) {
    // try to run remote system call
    Meteor.call('runCasperJS', function(err, res) {
      // check result
      if (err) {
        // Do some error notification
      } else {
        // Do some success action
      }
    });
  }
});
```

#### Resume

You need to place the server side methods into files on directory "yourproject/server" (e.g.) main.js and the client part into your template with the Button you wish to press (rename mytemplate to your defined one).

Hope you get out what you need.

Cheers
Tom

Comment: Thanks! It does work perfectly. I got some problems with the Bot location, then I create a folder called tests in my meteor project, in the method y need to change the path where the duolingo.js script bot was located like this. casperjs ../../../../../tests/duolingo.js --engine=slimerjs --disk-cache=no. And Works!